# adding a timer to implement reminders in application

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a reminders table in my apps database

```
FieldName = 'id'
FieldName = 'title'
FieldName = 'description'
FieldName = 'start_date'
FieldName = 'start_time'
FieldName = 'end_date'
FieldName = 'end_time'
FieldName = 'repeat'  (true/false)
FieldName = 'occurs'  (Integer = 1-Daily, 2-Weekly, 3-Monthy, 4-Annually)
FieldName = 'completed" (true/False)
```

Is there a way to use a TTimer to display the title and description of the reminder whenever the event occurs?  If so, please explain in code/seudo code, or text.

a reminder is either a onetime - or - re-occurring event

if one time (occurs = 1 daily) , the date and time is stored in the Start_Date & Start Time
The reminder should display at that time. After displayed, table field "Completed" is set to true.

if re-occurring, the date and time is stored in the Start_Date & Start Time
and the End Date and End Time is stored.  The reminder should display at that day and time, each day (1), week (2), month(3), or year(4)

If daily, reminder should display at that time every day, until end date is reached

If weekly, reminder should display at that time, on that particular day (of each week), until end date is reached

If monthly, reminder should display at that time, on that particular day (of each month), until end date is reached

If Annually, reminder should display at that time, on that particular day (of each year), until end date is reached

when end date is reached, Completed is updated with True

thanks, i hope this is easily do-able with out any additional components or libraries

Comment: "please explain in code." - This sounds more like you want someone to do your work for you.

Comment: No, i don't want someone to do my code. If I could explain in code, i would. I can't, therefor, i explained in text. If you dont want to provide an answer, that is your perogative. if you or someone would like to explain to me how to do this without giving me code, Im open to any and all suggestions. - thanks

Comment: There, i changed my question to ask for either or....thanks for showing me my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i couldn't figure out how to post all the code, but here is the main TTimer Event

```
Procedure TForm1.Timer1Time(Sender: TObject);
var
 CommandText: String;
begin
 try
  Timer1.Enabled:= False;
  if ADOQuery1.Active then 
   ADOQuery1.Active:= False;
  CommandText :=
  Format('SELECT * FROM REMINDERS WHERE (START_DATE <= %s) AND (COMPLETED = FALSE) AND (LASTCHECK < %s)',
    [FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yy', Date), FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yy', Date)]);
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := CommandText;
try
  ADOQuery1.Active := True;
  if not ADOQuery1.IsEmpty then
  begin
    BuildReminderList(ADOQuery1);
  end;
except
  //
end;
finally
Timer1.Enabled := True;
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

<ironic>

**Your question:**
Is there a way to use a TTimer to display the title and description of the reminder whenever the event occurs?

**My answer**

Yes, is there a way to do it.

**Requirement:**
If so, please explain in code.

**Anwer to fillfull your requirement**

pseudocode:

```
procedure TEventsManager.SetNextEventTimer;
begin
  if Assigned(NextOcurringEvent) then
  begin
    Timer1.Interval := MillisecondsBetween(Now, NextOcurringEvent.DateTime);
    Timer1.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TEventsManager.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  DisplayReminder(nextOcurringEvent);
  SetNextEventTimer;
end;
```

</ironic>

Comment: Why the irony? Why not just answer it seriously?

Comment: I agree. I I dont understand the Irony myself. Especially coming from someone with such a great reputation. I Guess that repution comes at the expense of others.

Comment: @Rob, @Shane: I'm sorry, I was a bit tired of reading incomplete questions at the moment of writing, also feeling @Shane laziness asking us for a complete idea (with code) without any real effort to create his own and ask maybe for validation/enhancement.  I thought several times before click the post button, but I feel it was fair at the moment and even with irony my pseudo-code is a good point to start for someone clueless about the thing, just trying to make s/he burn some brain to do it.  Maybe I'm wrong... I have no regrets and of course nothing personal to @Shane.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said without additional components, but I think you'll like this.

In JVCL, there's a component called TJvScheduledEvents which can do exactly what you need and you can use it with very little programming. Try it and if you have any questions about it, feel free to ask.

Comment: is this component a dataaware component, or is the library compatible with database?

Comment: TJvScheduledEvents component itself is not db-aware but it has a property called AppStorage which can be assigned one of TJvAppIniFileStorage, TJvAppRegistryStorage or TJvAppDBStorage. Those in turn give you possibility to store properties into IniFile, Registry or Database respectively. You should install JVCL and try it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, im not interested in storing anything in the database. Merely trying to read from the database at a certain interval, looking for reminders that are due, and siaplying them. After they are due, then updating the completed field to True. Simple as that. My question still stands. Can i do this with a TTimer, and How. The How part would of course mean how do i figure out the date portion to determine if a reminder is due for diplay.

Comment: @Shane, if your events are in a database, then what you've just described means you *are* interested in storing things in a database. But anyway, no, the JvScheduledEvents class will not handle your whole program for you. You'll still have to do some work. It will take care of event-scheduling for you, you still need to tell it what your events are and decide what to do when an event occurs. How your program is notified of *new* events is a separate matter. Maybe your database supports triggers. Or, as you said, you can just poll the database with a timer.

Comment: IMO, I wouldn't use simple TTimer for reminders because you have to set the Interval property to 1000 ms to get a more or less good resolution for your timers to be precise. In that case, OnTimer event will be called every second which uses CPU time. Using components like TJvScheduledEvents is more appropriate for what you want to do because it's using a different mechanism to fire events. I recommend you try it before making decision whether or not to use it.

Comment: Another bad thing about TTimer is that you can't tell it WHEN to fire but HOW OFTEN, which is not good for reminders.

Comment: I only need it to fire every minute (60000). I can do a threaded ttimer if needed down the road, but for my simple case, i dont believe it is needed.  This app is not a continously used app. It doesn't have processing going all the time. There will not be many items in the table, and at most, it may only display 2 reminders a day (most likey one every few days, once a week, once a month, or once a year).  I believe i have come up with a solution using TTimer and straight delphi 7 code (no component or library needed) - thanks